# Uber SSO login issue in iOS 8 Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, uber-api

I am trying to integrate Uber Ride SDK in my app.

Use this code to add Uber login button

```
whiteLoginButton = LoginButton(frame: CGRectZero , scopes: [.Profile, .Places], loginManager: LoginManager(loginType: .Native))
whiteLoginButton.presentingViewController = self
whiteLoginButton.delegate = self
whiteLoginButton.colorStyle = .White
blackView.addSubview(whiteLoginButton)
```

and for delegation use this

```
extension ViewController : LoginButtonDelegate{
    func loginButton(button: LoginButton, didLogoutWithSuccess success: Bool) {
        self.showMessage("Logout Success")
    }
 func loginButton(button: LoginButton, didCompleteLoginWithToken accessToken: AccessToken?, error: NSError?) {
        if accessToken != nil {
 self.showMessage("Got an AccessToken!")
   } else {
            // Error
    }
}
```

Code not working for native type login in app.
In details SSO login not redirect from **official uber app back to my app with access token.**

**All callback URL and settings are verified from other sample and working in IOS 9+**

Comment: https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/issues/69

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently uber SDK in beta so there is possibly multiple issues is there. 
let wait uber developer team can resolve it ASAP.